# Using the django admin's site authentication in a non-admin view

Tags: django, authentication, admin

I am writing a simple django app to manage pages on a website.
The pages are created through the admin site and can be previewed using the 'view on site' function.
Each page has a 'published' boolean that determines whether the view that displays pages should show it on site.
Of course, once I change the view to respect 'published' the admin page's 'view on site' link will not show the page either.
But I want to be able to preview unpublished pages during the editing process.

So I decided to change the view to check whether there is an authenticated user associated with the request.
For example:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff:
    manager=Pages.objects    #returns all pages
else:
    manager=Pages.live       #only returns published pages
```

Then the appropriate manager is passed to get_object_or_404 along with the page_id captured from the URL

However, in the view, user is always Anonymous even when a user who is authenticated with the admin site clicks the 'view on site' link.
So the 'live' manager always gets used and I have the same result as before: 404 when unpublished pages are accessed from the admin site.
Is this the way its supposed to behave? 
I really thought the session information would be inherited from the admin site's session.

I would appreciate any direction here because I may not be too clear on how this should work.
I don't need  a login mechanism for the site so I was hoping to piggyback off the admin's login to get the ability to view unpublished pages in the admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gone.
Now, if I am logged into admin I can view unpublished pages otherwise I get a 404 error.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure why it started working.
I ran some package updates (neither django nor Firefox was among them) and had to restart my (archlinux) machine.
When I restarted the django develpment server and tested the function again, all was well.
I suspect Firefox was the culprit but that's only a guess.

Anyway, thanks to anyone who gave the issue some thought.
I can stop pulling my hair out now.